# How to improve a weekly planning system to create an Excel spread sheet that doesn't not just list SUN as a day, but lists each day of the week?

Tags: python, openpyxl, planning

Here is the simple program that I am working on:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.exceptions import InvalidFileException
import webbrowser

CATEGORIES = {
    "Housing":        0.3,
    "Emergency Fund": 0.1,
    "Brokerage Account": 0.05,
    "Vacations": 0.05,
    "Entertainment": 0.08,
    "Restaurants": 0.05,
    "Clothing": 0.038,
    "Family": 0.05,
    "Christmas": 0.02,
    "Gifts": 0.02,
    "Hobbies": 0.1,
    "House Upgrades": 0.05,
    "Cable": 0.02,
    "Internet": 0.02,
    "Subscriptions": 0.02,
    "Lawn": 0.02,
    "Beauty Products": 0.02,
    "Gym Memberships": 0.02,
    "Mortgage": 0.18,
    "House Taxes": 0.05,
    "House Insurance": 0.02,
    "Electricity": 0.0235,
    "House gas": 0.02,
    "Water / Garbage": 0.02,
    "House Repairs": 0.05,
    "Other housing costs": 0.05,
    "Groceries": 0.1,
    "Vehicle Gas": 0.02,
    "Grandkids": 0.02,
    "Vehicle Taxes and Insurance": 0.05,
    "Vehicle Replacement": 0.05,
    "Oil Changes": 0.02,
    "AAA": 0.02,
    "Tires": 0.02,
    "Vehicle Repairs / Upkeep": 0.05,
    "Health Insurance Premiums": 0.1,
    "Healthcare Costs": 0.05,
    "Cell Phones": 0.05,
    "Credit Card Payments": 0.05,
    "CarPayments": 0.05,
    "Auto Insurance": 0.014
}
# Get the coffee and meal times for 5 different people for each meal
coffee_times = []
breakfast_times = []
lunch_times = []
afternoon_snack_times = []
dinner_times = []


def open_urls():
    urls = [
        "https://logon.vanguard.com",
        "https://robinhood.com",
        "https://blockfi.com",
        "https://mint.intuit.com/trends",
        "https://www.myfitnesspal.com/reports",
        "https://next.waveapps.com/",
        "https://www.ncsecu.org",
        "https://www.bankofamerica.com",
        "https://www.paypal.com",
        "https://www.advisorclient.com",
        "https://client.schwab.com",
        "https://dashboard.stripe.com",
        "https://www.buymeacoffee.com/dashboard",
        "https://www.udemy.com/",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/",
        "https://www.youtube.com/",
        "https://itunesconnect.apple.com/login",  
        "https://poe.com",
        "https://quora.com",
        "https://github.com/",  
        "https://stackoverflow.com",
        "https://nytimes.com",
        "https://wsj.com",
        "https://medium.com",
        "https://investopedia.com",
        "https://www.godaddy.com",
        "https://www.evan-gertis.com",
        "https://members.carolinas.aaa.com/login",
        "https://www.t-mobile.com/",
        "https://gourl.io/"
             
    ]
    
    for url in urls:
        webbrowser.open(url)

def prompt_user():
    top_priority = input("What is your top priority for the day? ")
    top_priority_date = input("When do you need to have this priority completed? (format: YYYY-MM-DD) ")
    second_priority = input("What is your second priority for the day? ")
    second_priority_date = input("When do you need to have this priority completed? (format: YYYY-MM-DD) ")
    third_priority = input("What is your third priority for the day? ")
    third_priority_date = input("When do you need to have this priority completed? (format: YYYY-MM-DD) ")
    advice = input("Who can you call for advice on achieving your goals? ")
    actions = input("What specific actions do you need to take to move closer to your objectives? ")
    devotional = input("Did you take 10-15 minutes for morning devotional or meditation? (yes/no) ")
    workout = input("Did you complete a 30-45 minute workout or core exercise routine? (yes/no) ")
    budget_review = input("Did you complete your weekly budget review and stick to your budget for the week (assuming an average spending amount of $176.1 per category)? (yes/no) ")
    overspending = {}
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        response = input(f"Did you overspend in {category}? If so, how much? (enter a number or '0' if not applicable) ")
        while not (response.isdigit() or response == "0"):
            response = input(f"Invalid input. Did you overspend in {category}? If so, how much? (enter a number or '0' if not applicable) ")
        overspending[category] = float(response)
    unexpected_expenses = {}
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        response = input(f"Were there any unexpected expenses that came up in {category}? If so, how much? (enter a number or '0'') ")
        while not (response.isdigit() or response == "0"):
            response = input(f"Invalid input. Were there any unexpected expenses that came up in {category}? If so, how much? (enter a number or '0') ")
        unexpected_expenses[category] = float(response)
    
    return {
        "top_priority": top_priority,
        "top_priority_date": datetime.datetime.strptime(top_priority_date, "%Y-%m-%d"),
        "second_priority": second_priority,
        "second_priority_date": datetime.datetime.strptime(second_priority_date, "%Y-%m-%d"),
        "third_priority": third_priority,
        "third_priority_date": datetime.datetime.strptime(third_priority_date, "%Y-%m-%d"),
        "advice": advice,
        "actions": actions,
        "devotional": devotional,
        "workout": workout,
        "budget_review": budget_review,
        "overspending": overspending,
        "unexpected_expenses": unexpected_expenses
    }

def calculate_budget(CATEGORIES, total_income):
    budget = {}
    for category, percentage in CATEGORIES.items():
        budget[category] = round(percentage * total_income, 2)
    return budget

def print_budget(budget):
    for category, amount in budget.items():
        print(f"{category}: ${amount}")

def main():
    try:
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("budget.xlsx")
    except InvalidFileException:
        print("Invalid file format.")
        return
    sheet = workbook.active
    open_urls()
    total_income = input("What is your income? ")
    total_income = float(total_income) # convert to float
    print(f"Total Income: ${total_income}")
    budget = calculate_budget(CATEGORIES, total_income)
    print_budget(budget)
    user_input = prompt_user()
    print(user_input)
    for i in range(5):
        name = input(f"Enter the name of person {i+1}: ")
        coffee_time = input(f"Enter the best time for coffee for {name}: ")
        coffee_times.append(coffee_time)
        breakfast_time = input(f"Enter the best time for breakfast for {name}: ")
        breakfast_times.append(breakfast_time)
        lunch_time = input(f"Enter the best time for lunch for {name}: ")
        lunch_times.append(lunch_time)
        afternoon_snack_time = input(f"Enter the best time for afternoon snack for {name}: ")
        afternoon_snack_times.append(afternoon_snack_time)
        dinner_time = input(f"Enter the best time for dinner for {name}: ")
        dinner_times.append(dinner_time)

    # Create a new Excel workbook
    wb = Workbook()

     # Create a new sheet
    results_sheet = wb.create_sheet("Results")

    # Write the headers
    headers = ["Category", "Overspending", "Unexpected Expenses"]
    for col_num, header in enumerate(headers, start=1):
        results_sheet.cell(row=1, column=col_num, value=header)
    
    # Write the results
    for row_num, category in enumerate(CATEGORIES, start=2):
        results_sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=1, value=category)
        results_sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=2, value=user_input['overspending'].get(category, 0))
        results_sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=3, value=user_input['unexpected_expenses'].get(category, 0))
    
    # Save the workbook
    wb.save("results.xlsx")

    # Create sheets for each section
    coffee_sheet = wb.active
    coffee_sheet.title = "Coffee"
    breakfast_sheet = wb.create_sheet("Breakfast")
    lunch_sheet = wb.create_sheet("Lunch")
    afternoon_snack_sheet = wb.create_sheet("Afternoon Snack")
    dinner_sheet = wb.create_sheet("Dinner")

    sheets = [coffee_sheet, breakfast_sheet, lunch_sheet, afternoon_snack_sheet, dinner_sheet]

    # Save schedules in each sheet
    meal_sections = [
        {"title": "Coffee", "times": coffee_times},
        {"title": "Breakfast", "times": breakfast_times},
        {"title": "Lunch", "times": lunch_times},
        {"title": "Afternoon Snack", "times": afternoon_snack_times},
        {"title": "Dinner", "times": dinner_times},
    ]

    for sheet, section in zip(sheets, meal_sections):
        sheet.cell(row=1, column=1, value=section["title"])
        sheet.cell(row=2, column=1, value="Day")
        sheet.cell(row=2, column=2, value="Time")
        sheet.cell(row=2, column=3, value="Person")

        for day in ["MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"]:
            for i, time in enumerate(section["times"]):
                row = i + 3
                name = f"{meal_sections[0]['times'][i]}" # assuming coffee_times is not empty
                sheet.cell(row=row, column=1, value=day)
                sheet.cell(row=row, column=2, value=time)
                sheet.cell(row=row, column=3, value=name)

                # For Sunday, add a row break
                if day == "SUN":
                    sheet.cell(row=row+1, column=1, value="")

    # Save the workbook to a file
    wb.save("weekly_schedule.xlsx")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The current output just shows a single in the weekly_schedule.xslx file. The expected output should show not just SUN but Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, And Sunday.

How can I move forward?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.exceptions import InvalidFileException
import webbrowser
import datetime


CATEGORIES = {
    "Housing":        0.3,
    "Emergency Fund": 0.1,
    "Brokerage Account": 0.05,
    "Vacations": 0.05,
    "Entertainment": 0.08,
    "Restaurants": 0.05,
    "Clothing": 0.038,
    "Family": 0.05,
    "Christmas": 0.02,
    "Gifts": 0.02,
    "Hobbies": 0.1,
    "House Upgrades": 0.05,
    "Cable": 0.02,
    "Internet": 0.02,
    "Subscriptions": 0.02,
    "Lawn": 0.02,
    "Beauty Products": 0.02,
    "Gym Memberships": 0.02,
    "Mortgage": 0.18,
    "House Taxes": 0.05,
    "House Insurance": 0.02,
    "Electricity": 0.0235,
    "House gas": 0.02,
    "Water / Garbage": 0.02,
    "House Repairs": 0.05,
    "Other housing costs": 0.05,
    "Groceries": 0.1,
    "Vehicle Gas": 0.02,
    "Grandkids": 0.02,
    "Vehicle Taxes and Insurance": 0.05,
    "Vehicle Replacement": 0.05,
    "Oil Changes": 0.02,
    "AAA": 0.02,
    "Tires": 0.02,
    "Vehicle Repairs / Upkeep": 0.05,
    "Health Insurance Premiums": 0.1,
    "Healthcare Costs": 0.05,
    "Cell Phones": 0.05,
    "Credit Card Payments": 0.05,
    "CarPayments": 0.05,
    "Auto Insurance": 0.014
}
# Get the coffee and meal times for 5 different people for each meal
coffee_times = []
breakfast_times = []
lunch_times = []
afternoon_snack_times = []
dinner_times = []


def open_urls():
    urls = [
        "https://logon.vanguard.com",
        "https://robinhood.com",
        "https://blockfi.com",
        "https://mint.intuit.com/trends",
        "https://www.myfitnesspal.com/reports",
        "https://next.waveapps.com/",
        "https://www.ncsecu.org",
        "https://www.bankofamerica.com",
        "https://www.paypal.com",
        "https://www.advisorclient.com",
        "https://client.schwab.com",
        "https://dashboard.stripe.com",
        "https://www.buymeacoffee.com/dashboard",
        "https://www.udemy.com/",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/",
        "https://www.youtube.com/",
        "https://itunesconnect.apple.com/login",  
        "https://poe.com",
        "https://quora.com",
        "https://github.com/",  
        "https://stackoverflow.com",
        "https://nytimes.com",
        "https://wsj.com",
        "https://medium.com",
        "https://investopedia.com",
        "https://www.godaddy.com",
        "https://www.evan-gertis.com",
        "https://members.carolinas.aaa.com/login",
        "https://www.t-mobile.com/",
        "https://gourl.io/"
             
    ]
    
    for url in urls:
        webbrowser.open(url)

def prompt_user():
    top_priority = input("What is your top priority for the day? ")
    top_priority_date = input("When do you need to have this priority completed? (format: YYYY-MM-DD) ")
    second_priority = input("What is your second priority for the day? ")
    second_priority_date = input("When do you need to have this priority completed? (format: YYYY-MM-DD) ")
    third_priority = input("What is your third priority for the day? ")
    third_priority_date = input("When do you need to have this priority completed? (format: YYYY-MM-DD) ")
    advice = input("Who can you call for advice on achieving your goals? ")
    actions = input("What specific actions do you need to take to move closer to your objectives? ")
    devotional = input("Did you take 10-15 minutes for morning devotional or meditation? (yes/no) ")
    workout = input("Did you complete a 30-45 minute workout or core exercise routine? (yes/no) ")
    budget_review = input("Did you complete your weekly budget review and stick to your budget for the week (assuming an average spending amount of $176.1 per category)? (yes/no) ")
    overspending = {}
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        response = input(f"Did you overspend in {category}? If so, how much? (enter a number or '0' if not applicable) ")
        while not (response.isdigit() or response == "0"):
            response = input(f"Invalid input. Did you overspend in {category}? If so, how much? (enter a number or '0' if not applicable) ")
        overspending[category] = float(response)
    unexpected_expenses = {}
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        response = input(f"Were there any unexpected expenses that came up in {category}? If so, how much? (enter a number or '0'') ")
        while not (response.isdigit() or response == "0"):
            response = input(f"Invalid input. Were there any unexpected expenses that came up in {category}? If so, how much? (enter a number or '0') ")
        unexpected_expenses[category] = float(response)
    
    return {
        "top_priority": top_priority,
        "top_priority_date": datetime.datetime.strptime(top_priority_date, "%Y-%m-%d"),
        "second_priority": second_priority,
        "second_priority_date": datetime.datetime.strptime(second_priority_date, "%Y-%m-%d"),
        "third_priority": third_priority,
        "third_priority_date": datetime.datetime.strptime(third_priority_date, "%Y-%m-%d"),
        "advice": advice,
        "actions": actions,
        "devotional": devotional,
        "workout": workout,
        "budget_review": budget_review,
        "overspending": overspending,
        "unexpected_expenses": unexpected_expenses
    }

def calculate_budget(CATEGORIES, total_income):
    budget = {}
    for category, percentage in CATEGORIES.items():
        budget[category] = round(percentage * total_income, 2)
    return budget

def print_budget(budget):
    for category, amount in budget.items():
        print(f"{category}: ${amount}")

def main():
    try:
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("budget.xlsx")
    except InvalidFileException:
        print("Invalid file format.")
        return
    sheet = workbook.active
    open_urls()
    total_income = input("What is your income? ")
    total_income = float(total_income) # convert to float
    print(f"Total Income: ${total_income}")
    budget = calculate_budget(CATEGORIES, total_income)
    print_budget(budget)
    user_input = prompt_user()
    print(user_input)
    for i in range(5):
        name = input(f"Enter the name of person {i+1}: ")
        coffee_time = input(f"Enter the best time for coffee for {name}: ")
        coffee_times.append(coffee_time)
        breakfast_time = input(f"Enter the best time for breakfast for {name}: ")
        breakfast_times.append(breakfast_time)
        lunch_time = input(f"Enter the best time for lunch for {name}: ")
        lunch_times.append(lunch_time)
        afternoon_snack_time = input(f"Enter the best time for afternoon snack for {name}: ")
        afternoon_snack_times.append(afternoon_snack_time)
        dinner_time = input(f"Enter the best time for dinner for {name}: ")
        dinner_times.append(dinner_time)

    # Create a new Excel workbook
    wb = Workbook()

     # Create a new sheet
    results_sheet = wb.create_sheet("Results")

    # Write the headers
    headers = ["Category", "Overspending", "Unexpected Expenses"]
    for col_num, header in enumerate(headers, start=1):
        results_sheet.cell(row=1, column=col_num, value=header)
    
    # Write the results
    for row_num, category in enumerate(CATEGORIES, start=2):
        results_sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=1, value=category)
        results_sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=2, value=user_input['overspending'].get(category, 0))
        results_sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=3, value=user_input['unexpected_expenses'].get(category, 0))
    
    # Save the workbook
    wb.save("results.xlsx")

    # Create sheets for each section
    coffee_sheet = wb.active
    coffee_sheet.title = "Coffee"
    breakfast_sheet = wb.create_sheet("Breakfast")
    lunch_sheet = wb.create_sheet("Lunch")
    afternoon_snack_sheet = wb.create_sheet("Afternoon Snack")
    dinner_sheet = wb.create_sheet("Dinner")

    sheets = [coffee_sheet, breakfast_sheet, lunch_sheet, afternoon_snack_sheet, dinner_sheet]

    # Save schedules in each sheet
    meal_sections = [
        {"title": "Coffee", "times": coffee_times},
        {"title": "Breakfast", "times": breakfast_times},
        {"title": "Lunch", "times": lunch_times},
        {"title": "Afternoon Snack", "times": afternoon_snack_times},
        {"title": "Dinner", "times": dinner_times},
    ]

    for sheet, section in zip(sheets, meal_sections):
        sheet.cell(row=1, column=1, value=section["title"])
        sheet.cell(row=2, column=1, value="Day")
        sheet.cell(row=2, column=2, value="Time")
        sheet.cell(row=2, column=3, value="Person")

        days_of_week = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
        for day_number, day in enumerate(days_of_week):
            for i, time in enumerate(section["times"]):
                row = i + 3 + (day_number * (len(section["times"]) + 3))
                name = f"{meal_sections[0]['times'][i]}" # assuming coffee_times is not empty
                sheet.cell(row=row, column=1, value=day)
                sheet.cell(row=row, column=2, value=time)
                sheet.cell(row=row, column=3, value=name)

    # Save the workbook to a file
    wb.save("weekly_schedule_2.xlsx")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It is good when one solves an issue oneself, and in general it is good to write up a self-answer. But this question is rather niche and may not be helpful to other readers. Moreover, an answer ideally will show what changes were made, and explain how they work or why they solve the problem, so that it is useful to future readers.